# Eroor django-urls

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-urls

```
from django.urls import path, re_path
from . import views
app_name="home-app"

urlpatterns = [
   path('nueva-url', IndexView.views(), name='index')#this synthesis does not work, it gives me an error.
]
```

My IDE draws a red line below `IndexView` like this:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

change your import statement:

```
from .views import IndexView

urlpatterns = [ 
    path('nueva-url', IndexView.as_view(), name='index')
]
```

Comment: Technically it'd be `from .views import IndexView`